# Data location of IBM i Apache server descriptions in HTTPAdmin interface

Tags: web-server, ibm-midrange

I'm working on replicating Apache servers to a HA box, and I can replicate the servers themselves correctly (QUSRSYS/QATMHINSTC and the associated files in /www/), but I cannot find where the description field is stored for the servers through the :2001/HTTPAdmin interface.

Couldn't find it mentioned anywhere, and I searched through the other QATM* files in QUSRSYS to no avail.

Where is it stored?

[image: HTTPAdmin server description interface]